# python взять строки из трёх файлов и собрать в один

Tags: python, строки

помогите пожалуйста
имеем 3 файла

one.txt

```
harry
max
ben
```

two.txt

```
1
2
3
```

three.txt

```
jo
mo
```

нужно при помощи python собрать все в один файл в виде

res.txt

```
harry:1:jo
max:1:jo
ben:1:jo
harry:1:mo
max:1:mo
ben:1:mo
harry:2:jo
max:2:jo
ben:2:jo
harry:2:mo
max:2:mo
ben:2:mo
harry:3:jo
max:3:jo
ben:3:jo
harry:3:mo
max:3:mo
ben:3:mo
```

все что смог сам это

```
one = open('one.txt', mode='r', encoding="utf-8")
one_ = one.readlines()
one = one_
print(one)
two = open('two.txt', mode='r', encoding="utf-8")
two_ = two.readlines()
two = two_
print(two)
three = open('three.txt', mode='r', encoding="utf-8")
three_ = three.readlines()
three = three_
print(three)
print(one, two, three)
```

а как это правильно вывести мне не понятно.

```
for i in one:
    for y in two:
        for z in three:
            print(i,':', z, ':', y)
```

выводит какой то бардак, помогите плз)

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Открываете все три файла и читайете из каждого по строке и выводите результат в четвертый. Вы вообще что-то пробовали самостоятельно сделать?

Comment: и в чем у вас непреодолимые трудности? или просто неохота ничего делать?

Comment: Вот, теперь делаете три вложенных цикла for по спискам one, two, three, в самом внутреннем выводите текущие элементы из каждого из списков, разделив их двоеточием.

Comment: `readline()` для считывания строки используйте

Comment: огромное спасибо, все оказалось так просто) думал намного сложнее будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вам мешают переводы строки. Попробуйте использовать `strip`. Ну и переменные нужно указывать в том же порядке, в каком идут циклы. И лучше использовать `f-string`, в вашем способе будут пробелы между значениями.

```
print(f"{i.strip()}:{y.strip()}:{z.strip()}")
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, все оказалось так просто) думал намного сложнее будет

Comment: @q34005 Да это только по началу. Главное начать делать задания, не пугаться и не лениться )